# How to get EOL character of any file in java

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to find the `EOL` character of a file. I have tried the following snippet:

```
java.io.FileInputStream inputStream = null;  
inputStream=new java.io.FileInputStream (inputFile.trim());
java.util.Properties p = new java.util.Properties(System.getProperties());  
p.load(inputStream);  
System.setProperties(p);  
String lineSeperator=System.getProperties().getProperty("line.separator");  
System.out.println("--"+lineSeperator);
```

The result i am getting here is always `\r\n`, Even if i am reading a Linux originated file where delimiter should be `\n`.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: This code is just reading a property file and taking the value of the property "line.separator" from that file or system properties if it's not present. It doesn't actually look at the line endings of the file.

Comment: Detect END OF LINE (EOL) in File with Java https://gist.github.com/goxr3plus/6923c59b008113d671e06e2787bccd99

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`System.getProperty("line.separator")` returns the default line separator of your operating system. It has nothing to do with what the line separator used by a given file is.

To find it, open the file as a character stream, and iterate over the characters until you find `'\r'` or `'\n'`. If you find `'\n'` first, the you have a unix file. If you find `'\r'` followed by `'\n'`, you have a windows file. If you find `'\r'` not followed by `'\n'`, you have an old Mac file.

This of course assumes that the file is a text file in the first place, that a single kind of EOL is used in the file, and that you know the encoding of the file. If you don't know the encoding, you might use the same algorithm and use a byte stream instead of a character stream.

Note that this is irrelevant, most of the time, since Java has APIs that read a file line by line, and handle all combinations of EOLs just fine.

Comment: nice explanation but i am still new to java so can u explain this with a piece of snippet

Comment: Thanx a lot.Actually did it before reading this link. thanx anyways

Comment: We need some code sir. I need to read the file and find if EOL is ("\r","n" or "\r\n") . It will have only one EOL . I am reaching with character stream but not \r or \n is printed.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are reading OS related property. If you are running this program in windows and even if your file was created on linux, you will get \r\n as line seperator. To find end of line in input file, you need to find some other way... maybe regular expression can help you.